# cross browser extension to take data from a usb and display

Tags: google-chrome-extension, browser, cross-browser, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions

I am starting to work on a browser extension that can take data from a usb and then display the data to the user. I am in early stages and researching about web to usb comms.

I am struggling to find out if I will be able to use webUSB API (as I want it to be used on most browsers) or if there are any alternatives. Any help or direction would be appreciated.

I have just been researching and unable to find any concrete answers

Comment: "I have just been researching and unable to find any concrete answers" --- That's not very concrete :-) What exactly have you found, and why wasn't it good enough? I know, answering my question is work, but if you put in this work, it will in turn help us answer your question.

Comment: It's unclear why the struggle as there is [caniuse page for the WebUSB](https://caniuse.com/webusb) API, which clearly says which browsers support it. There's no alternative, but you can write an external app which uses USB and communicates with the extension via nativeMessaging protocol.

Comment: @ThomasMueller Apologies, my confusion comes from this [page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/manifest.json/background). It says that "You can use any of the WebExtension APIs in the script, as long as you have requested the necessary permissions.". This has confused me as I cannot understand the distinction between webUSB and the webExtention APIs this part is talking about. Is webUSB API part of the webExtension APIs?

Comment: We should know what you mean by "to take data".
if you're talking about a usb device that independently exchanges data in both directions (like an Arduino) then webUSB API could be for you (I never used that API so I do not know any potential or pitfall).
If instead you wanted to refer to a common pendrive, then to take\read data from that device you should think of different APIs such as [File System Access API](https://web.dev/file-system-access/)

Comment: WebUSB is not a part of WebExtension API. WebUSB is a Web platform API so you can use it in any browser that supports it. You were confused by the name "WebExtension" as it misleadingly implies relation to various Web standards, but it simply means that extensions can use Web technology.